# Using Python to Calculate a field

Tags: arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I am trying to replace values in a single column using an else if statement, but I keep getting an Syntax error in line 2. I'm new to Python so it's probably an easy solution, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I am using ArcMap 10.1.

```
    def Replace(SrcLevel):
      if SrcLevel == 0:
        return "4-Other"
      elif SrcLevel == 1:
        retun "1-Primary"
      elif SrcLevel == 2:
        return "2-Middle"

    SrcLevel = Replace(!SrcLevel!)
```

Comment: ==instead of = ????

Comment: Take your function and paste it into a new empty Python script, then call it a few times with some dummy values to test the logic. Step through it with a debugger if you aren't sure what is going on. I recommend [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) as it's one of the better IDEs out there for Windows. Editing and testing Python code from within the Field Calculator is one of the most frustrating experiences imaginable for a beginner, so don't do it.

Comment: yes, I'll second that, I couldn't even get one of the ESRI VBA sample scripts to work in it yesterday....

Comment: question (I'm just learning python too) what happens if the SrcLevel isn't a 0, 1, or 2?

Comment: @Banger, Field Calculator will enter null if you don't return something. For example a function that only has the line `pass` in it will set all values to null. If you don't want this I would probably return the orginal field value in a final `else` statement.

Comment: Andrea, I rolled this question back to its previous version because your edits--which eliminated all the errors--made the answer and the comments incomprehensible. (Evidently the solution is contained in @Fezter's comment to PolyGeo's reply.)

Comment: @whuber, I think it would be best to have the working code added as either another answer (as [discussed on meta](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/801/how-should-the-question-asker-post-the-eventual-solution-they-used-if-they-based), but perhaps only the OP and mods can do this) or as an addition to the question itself (something anyone can do). I would also suggest PolyGeo's answer be accepted in either case.

Answer (score 8):

At least four things needed correction:

1. You need to use **return** rather than **print**
2. You need to use **==** rather than **=** on your if and elif statements (thanks @DanPatterson)
3. Take care with your indentation - your print (to become return) statements don't seem to line up
4. **return** statement was written in one place as **retun** [sic]

There are examples **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am no longer getting a syntax error for line 2, but now I'm getting a general error.  Any other suggestions? The link the examples page didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @PolyGeo your link links back to this question :)

Comment: Oops - link should be correct now @blah238

Comment: Hnmm, that is the Calculate Value tool, not quite the same as Calculate Field.

Comment: Perhaps you meant: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000

Comment: **retun** instead of **return** on line 5 could be it - also it would help if you can also include a screenshot of what you have in the tool dialog.

Comment: Right again @blah238 - link now goes to http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/

Comment: Is SrcLevel a numeric field?

Comment: No, SrcLevel is a string.